# How to get selected row in bootstrap modal using knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a master-detail page using Knockout JS as seen in the picture below
[image]

I have a problem to get the value from bootstrap modal in the details. For example, after clicked browse button at subsidiary client column, will appear a list of subsidiary client in bootstrap modal.
[image]

I can not get the values (SubsidiaryClientID, SubsidiaryClientNo, and Name) back to the parent page after clicked the select link. How to get these values and set to the parent page?

Here is the code:

**View: Create.cshtml**

```
<form action="~/Invoice/CreateKO" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Office</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="OfficeID" id="OfficeID" class="form-control" data-bind="options: Offices, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'OfficeID', optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', value: OfficeID"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Client</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" id="ClientID" data-val-required="The Client field is required."
                       data-val-number="The field Client must be a number." data-val="true" data-bind="value: ClientID" />
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <input type="text" name="ClientName" id="ClientName" readonly="readonly" value="" class="form-control" style="width: 280px" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: browseClient, enable: OfficeID()">...</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Subsidiary Client</th>
                        <th>Firm's Matter</th>
                        <th>eBilling Matter</th>
                        <th>Invoice No</th>
                        <th>Attachment</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: Invoices, visible: Invoices().length > 0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeInvoice">Remove</a></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: SubsidiaryClientID" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: SubsidiaryClientNo" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: SubsidiaryClientNo" readonly="readonly" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: browseSubsidiaryClient">...</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: FirmMatterNo" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: FirmMatterDescription" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: FirmMatterLocation" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: LocationDescription" readonly="readonly" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: browseFirmMatter">...</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ClientMatterID" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ClientMatterNo" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ClientMatterDescription" readonly="readonly" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: browseClientMatter">...</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: InvoiceNo" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <a href="#" data-bind="click: addInvoice">Add Row..</a>
        <br />
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<!-- Client Modal -->
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Client/_Modal.cshtml"); }

<!-- SubsidiaryClient Modal -->
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/SubsidiaryClient/_Modal.cshtml"); }

<!-- LookupFirmMatter Modal -->
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/LookupFirmMatter/_Modal.cshtml"); }

<!-- ClientMatter Modal -->
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ClientMatter/_Modal.cshtml"); }

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    <script>
        function Invoice() {
            var self = this;

            self.SubsidiaryClientID = ko.observable();
            self.SubsidiaryClientNo = ko.observable();
            self.SubsidiaryClientName = ko.observable();
            self.FirmMatterNo = ko.observable();
            self.FirmMatterDescription = ko.observable();
            self.FirmMatterLocation = ko.observable();
            self.LocationDescription = ko.observable();
            self.ClientMatterID = ko.observable();
            self.ClientMatterNo = ko.observable();
            self.ClientMatterDescription = ko.observable();
            self.InvoiceNo = ko.observable();

            self.browseSubsidiaryClient = function () {
                if ($("#ClientID").val() == "0") {
                    alert("Please select client");
                    $("#btnLookupClient").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/SubsidiaryClient/Lookup?officeID=")' + $("#OfficeID").val() + '&clientID=' + $("#ClientID").val(),
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (!data.message) {
                        $("#lookup-subsidiaryclient-container").html(data);
                        $("#subsidiaryClientModal").modal({ show: true, backdrop: true });
                    } else {
                        $("#subsidiaryClientModal").modal("hide");
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                });
            };
            self.browseFirmMatter = function () {

            };
            self.browseClientMatter = function () {

            };
        }
        function InvoiceCreateViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            // Non-editable data
            self.Offices = ko.observableArray();

            // Editable data
            self.OfficeID = ko.observable();
            self.ClientID = ko.observable(0);
            self.Invoices = ko.observableArray([]);

            // Operations
            self.browseClient = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Client/LookupHasEBilling?c_officeID=")' + $("#OfficeID").val(),
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (!data.message) {
                        $("#lookup-client-container").html(data);
                        $("#clientModal").modal({ show: true, backdrop: true });
                    } else {
                        $("#clientModal").modal("hide");
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                });
            }
            self.addInvoice = function () {
                self.Invoices.push(new Invoice());
            };
            self.removeInvoice = function (invoice) {
                self.Invoices.remove(invoice);
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var invoiceCreateViewModel = new InvoiceCreateViewModel();

            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Office/GetOffices")", null, function (data) {
                invoiceCreateViewModel.Offices(data);
            });

            ko.applyBindings(invoiceCreateViewModel);

            $("#subsidiaryClientModal").on("click", "#btnSubmitSubsidiaryClient", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/SubsidiaryClient/Lookup")",
                    data: {
                        officeID: $("#OfficeID").val(),
                        clientID: $("#ClientID").val(),
                        filterField: $("#SubsidiaryClientFilterField").val(),
                        filterOperator: $("#SubsidiaryClientFilterOperator").val(),
                        filterValue: $("#SubsidiaryClientFilterValue").val()
                    },
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $("#lookup-subsidiaryclient-container").html(data);
                });
            });
        });

        function setClient(clientID, name) {
            document.getElementById("ClientID").value = clientID;
            document.getElementById("ClientName").value = name;

            $("#clientModal").modal("hide");
        }

        function setSubsidiaryClient(subsidiaryClientID, subsidiaryClientNo, name) {
            document.getElementById("SubsidiaryClientID").value = subsidiaryClientID;
            document.getElementById("SubsidiaryClientNo").value = subsidiaryClientNo;
            document.getElementById("SubsidiaryClientName").value = name;
            $("#subsidiaryClientModal").modal("hide");
        }
    </script>
}
```

**View: _Modal.cshtml (SubsidiaryClient's Modal)**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="subsidiaryClientModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Lookup Subsidiary Client</h4>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {

                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.DropDownList("SubsidiaryClientFilterField",
                            new List<SelectListItem>
                            {
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "Subsidiary Client No", Value = "SubsidiaryClientNo" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "Name", Value = "Name" }
                            },
                            new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.DropDownList("SubsidiaryClientFilterOperator",
                            new List<SelectListItem>
                            {
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "Contains", Value = "Contains" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "Does Not Contain", Value = "Does Not Contain" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "=", Value = "=" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "<>", Value = "<>" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = ">", Value = ">" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "<", Value = "<" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = ">=", Value = ">=" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "<=", Value = "<=" }
                            },
                            new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBox("SubsidiaryClientFilterValue", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter keyword" })
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitSubsidiaryClient" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="lookup-subsidiaryclient-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Lookup(short officeID, int clientID, string filterField, string filterOperator, string filterValue, int? page)
{
    var subsidiaryClients = db.SubsidiaryClients.Where(sc => sc.OfficeID == officeID && sc.ClientID == clientID);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue))
    {
        if ("Contains".Equals(filterOperator))
        {
            subsidiaryClients = subsidiaryClients.Where(filterField + ".Contains(@0)", filterValue);
        }
        else if ("Does Not Contain".Equals(filterOperator))
        {
            subsidiaryClients = subsidiaryClients.Where("!" + filterField + ".Contains(@0)", filterValue);
        }
        else
        {
            subsidiaryClients = subsidiaryClients.Where(filterField + " " + filterOperator + " @0", filterValue);
        }
    }

    subsidiaryClients = subsidiaryClients.OrderBy(sc => sc.Name);

    ViewBag.officeID = officeID;
    ViewBag.clientID = clientID;
    ViewBag.filterField = filterField;
    ViewBag.filterOperator = filterOperator;
    ViewBag.filterValue = filterValue;

    var pagedSubsidiaryClients = subsidiaryClients.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, Global.RowsPerPage);
    var subsidiaryClientsVM = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SubsidiaryClient>, IEnumerable<SubsidiaryClientViewModel>>(pagedSubsidiaryClients.ToArray());
    var pagedSubsidiaryClientsVM = new StaticPagedList<SubsidiaryClientViewModel>(subsidiaryClientsVM, pagedSubsidiaryClients.GetMetaData());

    return PartialView("_Lookup", pagedSubsidiaryClientsVM);
}
```

**Partial View to display SubsidiaryClient's data:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Subsidiary Client No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:setSubsidiaryClient('@item.SubsidiaryClientID', '@item.SubsidiaryClientNo', '@item.Name.Replace("'", "\\'")')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></a></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubsidiaryClientNo)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Assuming the list of subsidiary client is an observable array having an observable field which defines whether the client is Active or not. When you open the list and clicks on clients you want on parent page, the click event will make this active observable field true/false as per the need and when the modal is closed you will have the list on the parent page by checking the observable field.

Comment: Thanks @Haridarshan, could you provide the sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Willy, I've worked on asp .net so am providing just a sample code in knockout and html. Hope this helps you

**HTML**

```
// Parent Page Code
<!-- ko foreach: ClientList -->
<!-- ko if: isActive -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text: SubsidiaryClientID"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text: SubsidiaryClientNo"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text: SubsidiaryClientName"></div>
</div>
<!-- ko -->
<!-- /ko -->

// Modal Box List
<!-- ko foreach: ClientList -->
<div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="click: $parent.Add">
    <div class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text: SubsidiaryClientID"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text: SubsidiaryClientNo"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text: SubsidiaryClientName"></div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Knockout**

```
// Child view-model for Client List

SubsidiaryClientVM = function(){

    this.SubsidiaryClientID = ko.observable();
    this.SubsidiaryClientNo = ko.observable();
    this.SubsidiaryClientName = ko.observable();
    this.isActive = ko.observable(false);

}

// Parent view model
vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.ClientList = ko.observableArray();

    // fill the array on search etc...
    this.onSearch = function(){
        self.ClientList(jQuery.map(data.Clients, function (item) {
            return new SubsidiaryClientVM(item);
        }));
    }

    this.Add = function(item){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.ClientList, function(list){
            if(list.SubsidiaryClientID == item.SubsidiaryClientID){
                list.isActive(!list.isActive());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own attributes at each row and assign that ro to a js function.

Like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><a href="" data-SubClientID="@item.SubsidiaryClientID" data-SubClientNo="@item.SubsidiaryClientNo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign clickablerow"></a></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubsidiaryClientNo)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        </tr>
    }


$(document).on('.clickablerow','click',function()
{
    var clientid=$(this).attr('data-SubClientID');

    ....
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I've changed the link using `data-` and nothing happens.

Comment: I've checked the console but there is nothing error.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your js and see if it returns $(this).attr('data-SubClientID')

Comment: It doesn't hit the breakpoint, I placed the `$(document).on('.clickablerow','click',function()` in `$(document).ready(function () {` is it in the right place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82551/discussion-between-willy-and-persian-developer).